# Opposite to theme_get_setting To Set

Tags: theming

In the template.php file, we grab the theme settings:

```
if(theme_get_setting('fix_sidebar')){
...
        variable_set('fixed_navbar',1);
    }
```

Based on the theme setting(i.e fix_sidbar'), we want to reset another theme setting(i.e fixed_navbar) as you see above. However, it does not appear to be working. It is not showing up theme settings that has:

```
 $form['style']['fixed_navbar'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Fixed Navbar'),
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('fixed_navbar'),
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
    );
```

How to do the opposite of theme_get_setting API to reset the setting with new value? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be doing this

```
$form['style']['fixed_navbar'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Fixed Navbar'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('fixed_navbar', 1),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
);
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. What is the difference between the two? I will try in couple hours and get back to approve your answer